# How to throw a server side error message in thickbox using php

Tags: php, smarty, thickbox

My prob in brief:

I am validating a registration form with server side using php and its working fine.

Now my prob is i need to show the error message using thickbox like popup.

Is that possible. If yes please explain how?

thanks in advance

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox/thickbox.js"></script>
<link href="thickbox/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<span class="prtexterror" style="color:#FF0000;display:none;" id="hiddenModalContent" >{$error_login}</span>


{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function() {
    tb_show("Please, login", "?tb_inline=true&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&height=180&width=300&modal=true", null);
});



</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: @Shiki: this code loading the popup but not the error message

Answer (score 0):

I glanced at Thinkbox's documentation. It seems that you must put your error message on a div with an id:

```
<div id="errorMessage">
{$errorMessage}
</div>
```

Your script should then provide the id of the div to be shown in the **inlineId** parameter:

```
tb_show("HAI","#TB_inline? height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=errorMessage&amp;modal=true",null);
```

Comment: Still id didn't get any thing in the popup. Any other way

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have had a quick look at the [Thickbox Documentation and Examples](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#container-4), specifically the one I believe you are using as a framework to create this functionality.

It is not terribly well explained in the documentation, but the "**hiddenModalContent**" referred to in the **href** actually refers to a DIV element which contains the text to be displayed in the Thickbox which popsup. So if you have no element with an ID of "*hiddenModalContent*" that would explain why you are getting an empty popup.

The solution? Replace:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?height=240&amp;width=405&amp;inlineId=hiddenModalContent&amp;modal=true" class="thickbox">{$errorMessage}</a>
```

With:

```
<div id="hiddenModalContent" style="display:none;">{$errorMessage}</div>
```

Then, when the `$(document).ready(...` executes, the content of that DIV will be used as the content of the Thickbox.

Comment: i didn't get any thing in the popup yet. any other way

Comment: What I have described here is what the Thickbox Documentation would suggest is how to use itself. The essence is that there MUST be an element in the page which contains the message you want show, and the call to Thickbox MUST have the ID of that element as the "`inlineId`" value. That is the ONLY way it will work.

Is the `$errorMessage` variable actually returning any content?